# SVG Scaling - % of window height or width

Tags: javascript, html, css, svg

Someone who has seemed to disappear wrote this code for me and I'm trying to figure out how to modify it to fit me current needs.

I'd like to scale the icon.svg graphic a % of height and/or % of width what ever is smaller. Currently the svg is too tall.

Reference site
http://kruegermultimedia.com/

Current Code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Krueger Multimedia</title>
    <style>
body {
background-color: #000000;
}
</style>
    <style>
    .logo {
            position: fixed;
            top: 50%;
            left: 50%;
            transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
            -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
            -moz-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
            -o-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
            -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body onresize="resize()">
    <div class="logo">
        <img id="logo" src="icon.svg" />
    </div>
    <script>
        var logo = document.getElementById('logo'),
            mult = 0.8;

        var resize;
        (resize = function() {
            var w = window.innerWidth,
                h = window.innerHeight;
            if (w < h) {
                var width = (w * mult);
                logo.width = width;
            } else {
                var height = (h * mult);
                logo.width = height;
            }
        })();
    </script>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use 'vmin' for the height or width of your image. 'vmin' will scale your image by the aspect of the view which is smaller. 1vmin is relative to 1%.

```
    .logo {
        position: fixed;
        top: 50%;
        left: 50%;
        transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
        -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
        -moz-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
        -o-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
        -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    }

    .logo img {
        height: 75vmin;
    }
```

Alternatively you can use 'vmax' to scale your image by the aspect of the view which is larger.

You can read more here: https://www.w3schools.com/CSSref/css_units.asp.

Comment: Thank you Soren. I tried that and it moved the icon.svg off the top left of the display. Is there a way to sue the vmin and keep the image centered?

Comment: Hey Truthen. Sorry about that, this is happening because the property should be added to the image itself, not the container. Remove the hard coded 'width' property from your <img> tag and then target the image with CSS. I have updated the answer above to reflect this.